# How to Class Dump Cydia?

Tags: ios, jailbreak, cydia

I've seen a lot of Flex Patches for Cydia, but every time I try to process Cydia it just takes for ever and then crashes Flex. I'm on the latest Flex 2 version and it's not a cracked version.

So I thought to use Class Dump, but how to use Class Dump on Cydia?

Comment: It's open source: http://gitweb.saurik.com/cydia.git

Answer (score 1):

Copy the Cydia executable from your phone to your Mac:

```sh
scp root@iphone-ip-address:/Applications/Cydia.app/MobileCydia .
```

Then, run class-dump on the executable file:

```sh
class-dump MobileCydia -H .
```

I ran it and got these generated headers:

```sh
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff   2341 Aug 15 15:50 Database.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff    452 Aug 15 15:50 CyteWebViewTableViewCell.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff   2634 Aug 15 15:50 CyteWebViewDelegate-Protocol.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff   6046 Aug 15 15:50 CyteWebViewController.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff   1916 Aug 15 15:50 CyteWebView.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff    686 Aug 15 15:50 CyteViewController.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff    226 Aug 15 15:50 CyteTableViewCellDelegate-Protocol.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff    362 Aug 15 15:50 CyteTableViewCellContentView.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff    444 Aug 15 15:50 CyteTableViewCell.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff    605 Aug 15 15:50 CyteTabBarController.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff    850 Aug 15 15:50 CydiaWebViewController.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff    360 Aug 15 15:50 CydiaURLProtocol.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff    998 Aug 15 15:50 CydiaTabBarController.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff    548 Aug 15 15:50 CydiaRelation.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff   1134 Aug 15 15:50 CydiaProgressEvent.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff   1079 Aug 15 15:50 CydiaProgressData.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff    520 Aug 15 15:50 CydiaOperation.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff   2708 Aug 15 15:50 CydiaObject.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff    260 Aug 15 15:50 CydiaLoadingViewController.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff    433 Aug 15 15:50 CydiaLoadingView.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff   1024 Aug 15 15:50 CydiaDelegate-Protocol.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff    508 Aug 15 15:50 CydiaClause.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff   3578 Aug 15 15:50 Cydia.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff    341 Aug 15 15:50 ConfirmationControllerDelegate-Protocol.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff    936 Aug 15 15:50 ConfirmationController.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff    744 Aug 15 15:50 ChangesController.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff    454 Aug 15 15:50 CYWebPolicyDecisionMediator.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff    315 Aug 15 15:50 CYURLCache.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff   1169 Aug 15 15:50 CYPackageController.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff  14392 Aug 15 15:50 CDStructures.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff    317 Aug 15 15:50 AppCacheController.h
drwxr-xr-x  113 username  staff   3842 Aug 15 15:50 .
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff    237 Aug 15 15:50 (null)-NSCoder.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff    325 Aug 15 15:50 (null)-MenesYieldToSelector.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff    326 Aug 15 15:50 (null)-MenesRadixSortWithSelector.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff    252 Aug 15 15:50 (null)-MenesInvocationWithSelector.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff    215 Aug 15 15:50 (null)-CyteDispatchEvent.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff    302 Aug 15 15:50 (null)-Cyte.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff    201 Aug 15 15:50 (null)-CydiaSecure.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff    224 Aug 15 15:50 (null)-CydiaScript.h
-rw-r--r--    1 username  staff    242 Aug 15 15:50 (null)-Cydia.h
```

Class dump did its work in no time at all (less than a second).

If `class-dump` fails, you probably have an outdated version of class dump.  The one I used was from the newest installation of [iOSOpenDev](http://www.iosopendev.com).

Comment: Can you send me the Dumped Cydia Folder? Would love that. Email: